# Microsoft Graph client send email

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I create a project using Microsoft Graph client for sending email. It is work on my web project. Now I create the console app but the receiver doesn't received email and no error is catch on my code. I put the  Console.WriteLine to debug. However I cannot see any error message or "finished" that is my last console writeLine.  In CMD, I see "start to SendMail" and the exe is end. Would someone help me what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

There is my code to send email:

```
 Private Async Sub SendMail(ByVal sSubject As String, ByVal sTextBody As String)


    Console.WriteLine("start to SendMail")
    Dim tenant As String = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("tenantID")
    Dim appID As String = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("appID")
    Dim secret As String = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("secretID")
    Dim graphEmail As MyEmail.GraphEmail = New MyEmail.GraphEmail(tenant, appID, secret)
    Try


        Dim body As String = "START TIME: " & startTime.ToString & Environment.NewLine
        body &= "END TIME: " & endTime.ToString & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
       
       
    
        Dim mailInfo As MyEmail.MailInfo= New MyEmail.MailInfo()
        mailInfo.To = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("TO")
        mailInfo.From = Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FROM")
        mailInfo.Subject = sSubject
        mailInfo.Body = body
        Dim result As String = Await graphEmail.SendEmail(mailInfo)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
        Console.ReadLine()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace.ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("finished")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your configuration definitely setup correctly? Possibly write your config settings to console as you use them, or debug and see.

Comment: What happens if you move the `Try` to the line after the you wright "start to SendMail"?